# xelatex compilation of devanagari documents looks BAD!

Tags: xetex, ligatures

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec, polyglossia, devanagaridigits}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1.5]{DejaVu Sans}
\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{veelo}

\chapter{भाग १}

घड्याळात --- एवढ्यात

\end{document}
```

My editor (KATE) uses the same font (DejaVu Sans). And displays the text correctly. See attached image. When compiled, the document produces square boxes!

[image: How it appears in my editor - KATE]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything, really, about Devanagari script and typesetting. Fixing the missing em-dash ligature issue is easy, though: Instead of `\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1.5]{gargi}`, write `\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1.5, Ligatures={TeX}]{gargi}`.

Comment: @Mico thanks. Ligatures={TeX} did solve the em-dash problem. But the ligature problem remains. This is the first time when a document looks better in the plain simple text editor than after processing with xelatex!

Comment: If it's that line we should look at, I wonder if most of the code in the example is needed. Have you tested if it's enough with `\documentclass{article}`, `\usepackage{fontspec}`, `setmainfont` and the line with the problem? In that case that should be the MWE.

Comment: @pst I agree, one can delete a lot of lines and still compile successfully. The reason I kept all those lines was to ensure that all package dependencies are clear.

Anyway, I am making it an 'M'WE :)

Comment: DejaVu Sans has no script Devanagari

Answer (score 1):

Those characters are not in DejaVu Sans. Earlier you used gargi and your question was why the ligatures you see in your editor were used. Then the answer was that gargi didn't have those ligatures. So this is really not about TeX. With this example:

```
% -*- TeX-engine: xetex; -*-% 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari, Ligatures=TeX]{Siddhanta}

\begin{document}

घड्याळात --- एवढ्यात

\end{document}
```

I showed that ligatures are used if they are in the font (this Siddhanta gotten [from here](http://www.svayambhava.org/)). These are not the same ligatures as the font in your text editor but looks like this:

[image]

I don't know which ligatures are good or bad, right or wrong here. You have to find a font that has the ligatures you want. If you don't know how to ask your editor what fonts it is using you could try a shell command like `fc-list :lang=hi` to show installed fonts suitable for writing Hindi with.

I think the font your have in your text editor is "Lohit Devanagari". It has ligatures of that kind anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question. The document displays perfectly in my editor (KATE on KDE) using DejaVu Sans as font. But when compiled, it just produces square boxes!!

Comment: DejaVu Sans doesn't have those characters. Your editor uses some other font for those. Did you try my answer you are commenting on?

Comment: (I've added an image now.)

Comment: @pst: you should use `Ligatures=TeX`

Comment: @Herbert, Yes, you are right. I focused on the other part, seeing that `---` was already answered in comments, but you are right, an answer should do that right as well, and I've updated it now.

Comment: @pst Yes. I did try your answer. It worked just the same as you have shown with Siddhanta font.

Also, in my editor, font is set to DejaVu Sans. Is it doing some auto-substituting?

Comment: Then I really don't know what you didn't like with my answer, since I think it answered everything in it that had to do with TeX.

I understand that you also need to know how to ask your editor what fonts it is using, or in some other way find that font. I've never used that editor, but I've edited my answer again now, helping you with the second option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the output is different from `xelatex` (picture on left) and `lualatex` (picture on right).

Your code is working on my computer and it should be all right as `gargi.ttf` is a part of official `ttf-indic-fonts-core` package in Linux. You could try the other fonts from that package, the files are `Kedage-b.ttf, Kedage-n.ttf, lohit_bn.ttf, lohit_gu.ttf, lohit_hi.ttf, lohit_ta.ttf, Malige-b.ttf, Malige-n.ttf, Meera_04.ttf, MuktiNarrowBold.ttf, MuktiNarrow.ttf, Pothana2000.ttf, Rachana_04.ttf, Rekha.ttf, utkal.ttf` and `Vemana.ttf`.

I am enclosing an example typeset in `Sanskrit2003.ttf`, a font which I have found among other fonts at http://salrc.uchicago.edu/resources/fonts/available/hindi/

```
%! xelatex mal-devanagari.tex
% and
%! lualatex mal-devanagari.tex
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{parskip, lastpage, tabu, booktabs, tfrupee, fontspec, polyglossia, devanagaridigits, setspace}
% http://salrc.uchicago.edu/resources/fonts/available/hindi/
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari, Scale=1.5, Ligatures=TeX]{Sanskrit2003.ttf}
%CODE2000.TTF ARIALUNI.TTF Sanskrit2003.ttf gargi.ttf
% http://www.omkarananda-ashram.org/Sanskrit/itranslator2003.htm#dls
% http://www.svayambhava.org/
\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\devanagarinumeral{section}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\devanagarinumeral{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\devanagarinumeral{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\devanagarinumeral{page}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\devanagarinumeral{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\chapter{भाग १}
घड्याळात --- एवढ्यात
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]